# CSS. Пример parallax эффекта на CSS, как изменить/убрать отступ сверху?

Tags: html, css, parallax

Подскажите пожалуйста, в этом  образце сайта с эффектом paralax на css, как изменить/убрать отступ сверху?

https://jsfiddle.net/MaximVelichkin/y5ajjbn1/

```css
/* ============================================================
  PRIMARY STRUCTURE
============================================================ */
.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* ============================================================
  SECTIONS
============================================================ */
section.module:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
section.module h2 {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}
section.module p {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
section.module p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
section.module.content {
  padding: 40px 0;
}
section.module.parallax {
  height: 600px;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
section.module.parallax h1 {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 600px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
section.module.parallax-1 {
  background-image: url("http://www.fonstola.ru/pic/201112/2560x1600/fonstola.ru-63832.jpg");
}
section.module.parallax-2 {
  background-image: url("http://hdoboi.net/uploads/hd/95263_krasivyiy_osenniy_peyzaj.jpg");
}
section.module.parallax-3 {
  background-image: url("http://drobs.ru/opyat/8/peyzazh_priroda_holmy_derevya_zelen_tuman_rassvet_solnce_5576x3087.jpg");
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  section.module h2 {
    font-size: 42px;
  }
  section.module p {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  section.module.parallax h1 {
    font-size: 96px;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 960px) {
  section.module.parallax h1 {
    font-size: 160px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="module parallax parallax-1">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Serene</h1>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="module content">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="module parallax parallax-2">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Rise</h1>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="module content">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="module parallax parallax-3">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Calm</h1>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="module content">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для некоторых элементов браузеры добавляют свои собственные стили. Исследовав элемент в дебаггере, выясняем что эта штука происходит и тут. Например в хроме у нас такой стиль:

```
:-webkit-any(article,aside,nav,section) h1 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0.83em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0.83em;
}
```

Аналогичные в других браузерах. Эти маржины и "распирают" наши секции, добавляя пустое пространство.

Соответственно мы можем закостылить это для конкретного случая обнулив конкретные маржины ручками.

```
section.module.parallax h1 {
  /* ваш код */
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Вообще во многих проектах обычно есть файлик со стилями с названием по типу reset.css или browser.css,  в котором стили юзер агента перетираются на корню, чтобы не было путаницы.